# C3js stacked Area-Spline chart won't stack

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm trying to do a stacked area chart using c3js like in [this example](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_area_stacked.html), however, my lines won't stack—they are just being placed on top of each other, like so:

[image]

Here's my code:

```js
 
c3.generate({
  data: {
    json: [
        {
          "metricDate": "2016-02-08",
          "vlp": 9046,
          "other": 904,
          "vdp": 10000,
          "home": 3543
        }, {
          "metricDate": "2016-02-09",
          "vdp": 7000,
          "other": 1103,
          "home": 3667,
          "vlp": 9542
        }, {
          "metricDate": "2016-02-10",
          "other": 1043,
          "vlp": 9751,
          "home": 3681,
          "vdp": 5000
        }, {
          "metricDate": "2016-02-11",
          "other": 1433,
          "home": 4059,
          "vdp": 4000,
          "vlp": 9924
        }
    ],
    type: 'area-spline',
    keys: {
      x: 'metricDate',
      value: ["vlp", "home", "vdp", "other"]
    }
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.16/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `groups` description, drop this line in after your type: area-spline line

```
groups:[['other','home','vdp','vlp']],
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
c3.generate({
  data: {
    json: [
        {
          "metricDate": "2016-02-08",
          "vlp": 9046,
          "other": 904,
          "vdp": 10000,
          "home": 3543
        }, {
          "metricDate": "2016-02-09",
          "vdp": 7000,
          "other": 1103,
          "home": 3667,
          "vlp": 9542
        }, {
          "metricDate": "2016-02-10",
          "other": 1043,
          "vlp": 9751,
          "home": 3681,
          "vdp": 5000
        }, {
          "metricDate": "2016-02-11",
          "other": 1433,
          "home": 4059,
          "vdp": 4000,
          "vlp": 9924
        }
    ],
    type: 'area-spline',
    groups:[['other','home','vdp','vlp']],
    keys: {
      x: 'metricDate',
      value: ["vlp", "home", "vdp", "other"]
    }
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.16/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chart"></div>
```